# Bad performance with OR operator

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to run a query over 582479 genes using the OR operator, after creating index on the properties: symbol, primaryidentifier, secondaryidentifier and name.
This the query:

```
PROFILE 
MATCH(g:Gene) WHERE g.symbol="CG11566" OR 
                    g.primaryidentifier="CG11566" OR
                    g.secondaryidentifier="CG11566" OR 
                    g.name="CG11566" 
RETURN g.id, g.primaryidentifier, g.secondaryidentifier, g.symbol, g.name
ORDER BY g.id;
```

The performance is very poor, the indexes created are not used but only the label scan-> 2912399 total db hits in 3253 ms

Changed the query to use UNION:

```
PROFILE 
      MATCH(g:Gene) WHERE g.symbol='CG11566' return g.id 
UNION MATCH(g:Gene) WHERE g.primaryidentifier='CG11566' return g.id 
UNION MATCH(g:Gene) WHERE g.secondaryidentifier='CG11566' return g.id 
UNION MATCH(g:Gene) WHERE g.name='CG11566' return g.id;
```

indexes have been used -> 8 total db hits in 73 ms. Much better.
Any better way to implement the query without using UNION?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not much else you can do right now, Cypher's planner would have to get cleverer

The UNION is imho the best solution right now.

Comment: Thanks Michael. It's really a shame!otherwise the AND operator works properly

Answer (score 1):

neo4j 3.2 has introduced the use of indexes with the OR operator. Great!

Answer (score 0):

You could split up the query into 4 parts (one for each condition) and collect all results into one array that's being unwinded in the last step:

```
MATCH (g1:Gene{symbol:'CG11566'})  
WITH collect(g1) as c1 
MATCH (g2:Gene{primaryidentifier:'CG11566'}) 
WITH c1 + collect(g2) as c2
MATCH (g3:Gene{secondaryidentifier:'CG11566'})
WITH c2 + collect(g3) as c3
MATCH (g4:Gene{name:'CG11566'})
WITH c3 + collect(g4) as c4
UNWIND c4 as gene
... do stuff with genes found by any of the 4 parts
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan. This solution reduces the number of db hits from 8 to 3. No sensible improvement in the execution time.

Comment: Do you have indexes for `Gene` and the four properties?

Comment: I've just noticed that the query doesn't work properly: If I run this simplified version PROFILE MATCH (g1:Gene{primaryidentifier:'CG11566'}) WITH collect(g1) as c1 
MATCH (g2:Gene{symbol:'CG11566'}) WITH collect(g2) + c1 as c2 IT WORKS and returns 1 gene. But if I run: PROFILE MATCH (g1:Gene{symbol:'CG11566'})  
WITH collect(g1) as c1 MATCH (g2:Gene{primaryidentifier:'CG11566'}) 
WITH collect(g2) + c1 as c2 IT RETURNS 0 genes. To notice that there is a gene with symbol CG11566 but not with primaryidentifier. It looks like that when it tries to apply c1(with 1 row) with g2 it returns 0 rows