# Simple Cypher Query for apoc dijkstra taking FOREVER

Tags: neo4j, cypher, query-optimization, gtfs

Maybe I am very stupid or **Neo4j** is not supposed to be fast. (Disclaimer: I am a Neo4j noob)

I have the following simple **dijkstra query** which is taking forever to run. I have to atleast wait for **5-10 minutes** for it to execute.Sometimes my Chrome browser crashes because of it.

**Sample Graph**

[image]

**Cypther Query**

```
profile MATCH  (startNode:Stop)--(st:Stoptime),
(endNode:Stop)--(et:Stoptime)
where  endNode.name = 'Hauptbahnhof Süd' and 
(startNode.name = 'Schlump' or startNode.name = 'U Schlump')     
call apoc.algo.dijkstra(st, et, 'PRECEDES', 'weight') YIELD path, weight
return startNode, endNode, path, weight
limit 100;
```

**Computer Config**

I am using a Ubuntu VM on windows machine which has 24GB Ram and 6 Cpus.

**Indexes**

[image]

**Sysinfo**
[image]

When I run profile on the above Query, i get the following information:

**Profile Information**

[image]

For the love of God, I cant figure out, where the **bottleneck** lies. I have checked all other answers on this, but to no avail.

Comment: Can you replace the current query plan with the expanded plan? Right now all we can see are rows and db hits, but we can't see how these correspond with the variables and operators in the query. Please expand all plan elements and add that in.

Comment: Done. Is it what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, thank you. As for the bottleneck, you can tell from the query that this is because of the number or rows generated even before the procedure runs. You have 5.1 million rows, so that will mean the procedure will run 5.1 million times, once per row. Are you expecting that many rows to be generated at that point? If not, something may be off about how you're performing your match.

Comment: long running queries are better be executed via cypher-shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't have the data set to test out my suggestion with, I can only point you in the direction that I would look. Hopefully, it leads you to the answer.

In looking at the profile and query I see that startNode and endNode are both type :Stop and that the Stop.name property is indexed.

When looking for endNode.name = 'Hauptbahnhof Süd' there are 3 estimated rows and 3 rows are returned.

However when looking for (startNode.name = 'Schlump' or startNode.name = 'U Schlump') there are 6 estimated rows, but 14827 returned.

Are there indeed 14827 :Stop nodes that contain either 'Schlump' or 'U Schlump'?

Or is it the 6 estimated rows? If the latter is the case can you run the query without the OR:

where  endNode.name = 'Hauptbahnhof Süd' and startNode.name = 'Schlump'

to see what the profiler comes up with.

If that performs as expected then the solution may be to rewrite the query to include that OR logic in a different format?

Perhaps
where  endNode.name = 'Hauptbahnhof Süd' and startNode.name IN ['Schlump','U Schlump']

Also found this [older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43933809/1598889) indicating an issue with the OR operator and indexes prior to 3.2.

I had remembered seeing another recent answer about some issue with OR, but can't seem to locate it now.

Good luck!

Comment: The number of estimated rows is only a rough estimate used to guide the cost planner before the query is executed; it will frequently not exactly match the actual number of rows obtained by an operation.

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40377002/neo4j-query-performance-tuning-undestanding

Comment: And thanks for the  suggestion to not use OR, I changed it everywhere

Comment: Did the change to not use OR speed up the query?

Comment: Hi, it did not change my query time, but atleast it made the code cleaner. Thanks